# Stop capturing any string based on / for urls in Django (regex)

Tags: python, regex, django, django-urls

So I'm using Django to build a webservice, but I've got a problem with the regexp in Urls.

I want to go to the localhost/user/USERNAME/products/ where the username can be any character, not just \w. I tried capturing it using this:

```
('^user/(?P<username>.+)/$', 'user'),
('^user/(?P<username>.+)/products/$', 'get_products'),
```

but ofc it captures the username 'USERNAME/products' and sends it to user. How should I say every possible character EXCEPT front slash for any length except zero?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `[^/]+` instead of `.+`.

As Chris Pratt notes below, `.+?` will also work, as it is a "non-capturing" regex, which will match any character until a match for the following sub-expression. I generally prefer normal eager solutions to non-capturing solutions where possible, because they do not introduce multiple evaluation rules.

Comment: Thanks, only for the first one, pointing to 'user' or for both of them?

Comment: `.+?` will also work. It will capture up to the next occurrence of `/`.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Yes, although I consider this more simple.